# ESP32 udp.write send packet but increasing packet

Tags: udp, esp32

My server sends the client a package containing the date and time in UNIX format, the first time my client asks the client for the correct date and time, he is able to update, but if I ask the date and time again, the server sends the previous time plus the current time, if I make the request again it sends this time the last 3 date and time and so on.

Upon reading the package received at the client, I see that the size increases by 10 characters with each new attempt. These 10 characters are the updated date and time

Server code:

```
int number = UnixTimeStamp;
char b[11];
String str;
str=String(number);
Serial.print("variável str ");
Serial.print(str);

str.toCharArray(b,11);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(b); i++)
{
udp.write(b[i]);
Serial.println(b[i]);
}
udp.endPacket();
```

Client code:

```
udp.parsePacket();
if(udp.read(buffer, 10) > 0){
    Serial.print("Server to client 1: ");


   Serial.println((char *)buffer);
}
```

Comment: you forgot to call  ```udp.beginPacket(udp.remoteIP(), udp.remotePort());``` prior your loop. And you do not need loop at all - just call ```udp.write(b);``` instead of loop

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answear. When I change the code to udp.write(b); I receive that error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' [-fpermissive]

Comment: Thanks now work's fine. I forgot this line:    udp.beginPacket(udp.remoteIP(), udp.remotePort());